# SMTP server in EC2 instance: Relay access denied

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp

I am trying to set up SMTP server in EC2 by installing postfix in EC2 Ubuntu instance. But when i try to run my nodeJS code to send mails, am getting the below error.

```
 Error: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 454 4.7.1 <recipient@yopmail.com>: Relay access denied
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\path\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:790:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionRCPT (C:\Users\path\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1654:28)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\path\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1607:30)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\path\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:969:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\path\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:755:14)
    at SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\path\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:193:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
  code: 'EENVELOPE',
  response: '454 4.7.1 <recipient@yopmail.com>: Relay access denied',
  responseCode: 454,
  command: 'RCPT TO',
  rejected: [ '<recipient@yopmail.com>' ],
  rejectedErrors: [
    Error: Recipient command failed: 454 4.7.1 <recipient@yopmail.com>: Relay access denied
        at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\path\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:790:19)
        at SMTPConnection._actionRCPT (C:\Users\path\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1640:24)
        at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\path\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1607:30)
        at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\path\burra\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:969:20)
        at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\path\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:755:14)
        at SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\path\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:193:44)
        at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
        at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
        at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
        at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
      code: 'EENVELOPE',
      response: '454 4.7.1 <recipient@yopmail.com>: Relay access denied',
      responseCode: 454,
      command: 'RCPT TO',
      recipient: '<recipient@yopmail.com>'
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure what went wrong and how am supposed to fix. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

I did set up the SMTP server and made necessary configurations like enabling the port, inbound settings in EC2. But none seem to work.

This is the code I've been trying to run.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'EC2_IP', // Replace with your EC2 instance public IP or domain
    port: 25,
    secure: false,
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    auth: {
        user: 'EC2_UBUNTU_LOGIN_USERNAME', // Use the system user associated with Postfix
        pass: 'EC2_UBUNTU_LOGIN_PASSWORD' // Use the system user's password
    }
});

const mailOptions = {
    from: 'sender@gmail.com',
    to: 'recipient@yopmail.com',
    subject: 'Test Email',
    text: 'This is a test email from your Node.js script.'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.error('Error:', error);
    }
    console.log('Email sent:', info.response);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send email using gmail in nodejs in 2023?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76472151/how-to-send-email-using-gmail-in-nodejs-in-2023)

Answer (score 0):

The reality is that you'll almost never be able to send email this way.  If you could then anyone on the planet could send email from your Gmail address as you from any machine.  Instead, your "from" address needs to come from a qualified host (as specified in the [SPF Record](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-spf-record/)).  Next, there is the [DKIM Record](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-dkim-record/) that the system receiving the email can use to verify that, in this case, Gmail was the actual sender of the email (and it wasn't).  These two are tied together using the [DMARC Record](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-dmarc-record/).

The short answer is that you can't impersonate a "from" domain anymore.  I would encourage you [take a look at other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76472151/how-to-send-email-using-gmail-in-nodejs-in-2023) for some additional details and what it will take to use your existing email.

Alternatively, register your own domain and use [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) service.  That's the standard way if you're in an AWS environment.